# Run multiple batch jobs in parallel Mule 4

Tags: runtime, mule, batch-processing, dataweave

I have a batch job that reads hundreds of images from an SFTP location and then encodes them into base64 and uploads them via API using HTTP connector.

I would like to make the process run quicker and hence trying to split the payload into 2 via scatter-gather and then sending then sending payload1 to one batch job in a subflow and payload2 to another batch job in another subflow.

Is this the right approach?

Or is it possible to split the load in just one batch process, ie for one half of the payload to be processed by batch step 1 and second half will be processed by batch step 2 at the same time?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a good approach. Batch jobs are always executed asynchronously (ie using different threads) so there is no benefit on using scatter-gather and it has the cons of increasing resource usage.

Splitting the payload in different batch steps doesn't make sense either. You should not try to scale by adding steps.

Batch jobs should be used naturally to work in parallel by iterating on an input. It may be able to [handle the splitting itself](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-processing-concept#mule-message-splitting-process) or you can manually split the input payload before. Then let it handle the concurrency automatically. There are some configurations you can use to tune it, like [block sizing](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#considerations-for-defining-a-block-size).